# Target other elements on d3.js on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I have a doughnut chart and I wanted to have an svg circle that serves as a button and scale the doughnut chart down as well as the circle in the middle, how to I target the the other element when I.

```
nav.on("click", function(d){
nav.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease("elastic")
    .attr("r", 60);
});
```

Lastly, is there a shorter way to do what I have done so far, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rP6dQ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you simply run the code in the handler that affects the other elements, e.g.

```
nav.on("click", function(d){
  nav.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease("elastic")
    .attr("r", 60);
  arc.outerRadius(radius/2);
  chart.transition().duration(1000).ease("elastic").attr("d", arc);
});
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rP6dQ/2/). The code itself looks fine to me.